# In WPF Datagrid, how to get ToolTip on keyboard focus using arrow keys?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, keyboard, tooltip

I am using an WPF DataGrid from codeplex. I have attached a Tooltip for each cell. This tooltip appears when the mouse hovers over the cell.

But can I provide **keyboardability to Tooltip**. If I use down arrow or up arrow to move between the DataGrid cells(basically when the cell gets focus), I want the tooltip to be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Make a custom ToolTip and try this:

**WPF Solution:**

- **XAML stuff:**

  ```
  <Button Canvas.Left="298" Canvas.Top="124" Height="34" 
    Name="button1"  Width="106" IsKeyboardFocusedChanged="showToolTip">
      Button
      <Button.ToolTip>
          <ToolTip>
              Whatever
          </ToolTip>
      </Button.ToolTip>
  </Button>
  ```
- **Generic Event Handler:** (So all controls can reference this event handler rather than making a new one for each control)
- ```
  public void showToolTip(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
      //Get tooltip from sender.
      ToolTip tt = (ToolTip)(sender as Control).ToolTip;
      //Places the Tooltip under the control rather than at the mouse position
      tt.PlacementTarget = (UIElement)sender;
      tt.Placement = PlacementMode.Right;
      tt.PlacementRectangle = new Rect(0, (sender as Control).Height, 0, 0);
      //Shows tooltip if KeyboardFocus is within.
      tt.IsOpen = (sender as Control).IsKeyboardFocusWithin;
  }
  ```

**WinForm Solution:** (I know you didn't ask for it, but I had it written, so I'll post it anyways.)

```
public class myUserControls: UserControl
{
    [Category("Category for UserControl")]
    public class ToolTipAdv : ToolTip
    {
        public ToolTipAdv (IContainer container) : base(container)
        {
            this.AutomaticDelay = 300;
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Highlight;
            this.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        }

        public void SetToolTip(Control ctrl, string caption)
        {
            ctrl.GotFocus += ShowToolTip;
            base.SetToolTip(ctrl, caption);
        }
        public void ShowToolTip(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string message = base.GetToolTip((Control)sender);
            base.Show(message, (IWin32Window)sender, (sender as Control).Location);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @Caorylulu : Can you be more elaborate ? I did not understand what you meant by your code. If you extend ToolTip class you wont get methods like base.SetToolTip(..) etc.

Comment: It will not work 
When we use like this   "  (ToolTip)(sender as Control).ToolTip; "
we will get string not ToolTip property.